# What this Rewrite rule in htaccess means?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can someone please help me understand this in `.htaccess` file?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.abc.lk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.lk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Further, I want to redirect all requests coming to `www.abc.com` to `abc.com`.

Thanks,
Bhathiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means:If the host is not equal to exactly `www.abc.lk` then redirect to `www.abc.lk/the/original/path`

As for part two of your question, This will set up the redirect `www.abc.lk` -> `abc.lk`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc\.lk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc.lk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Just be sure to not include the original two lines you have in your post.

Comment: What does [NC] means? Can you please explain what each part of `RewriteRule` means?